# OpenCV python vs C++ performance

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I've been doing some app using OpenCV first in Python, then I wanted to go to C++ for better perfs.... and it's doing much worse!

Am I doing anything wrong?

Even just testing with very easy functions seem to be slower in C++ for me.

```cpp
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        // Blur close edges (letters) together to keep text areas as a patch
        cv::GaussianBlur(work, work, cv::Size(41, 41), 0);
        cv::threshold(work, work, 30, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
        cv::GaussianBlur(work, work, cv::Size(41, 41), 0);
        cv::threshold(work, work, 30, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << "Time 1 " << work.rows << "\t" << work.cols << ": " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t).count() << "\n";
```

```py
        t = time.time() * 1000
        blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(edges, (41, 41), 0)
        blur = cv2.threshold(blur, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
        blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(blur, (41, 41), 0)
        blur = cv2.threshold(blur, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
        t2 = time.time() * 1000
        print(blur.shape, t2 - t)
```

yields:

```
Time 1 450      600: 220 # About 200+ms in C++
(450, 600) 1.992431640625 # 100x faster in python!
```

I am building from source the OpenCV c++, while I'm using opencv-python in python. Could it be that the build for python is *highly* optimised?
If so, what can I give to compiler to build OpenCV with as much optimisation?

Thanks,

Comment: how did you compile? Compiler optimizations turned on?

Comment: Left it as default so far, will try with optimizations on. But the difference seems huge to me so far!

Comment: Are you comparing the Debug version of c++ with the Python program?

Comment: time.time() measure **wall** time, your clocks are not comparable. at least use `cv::getTickCount()` for both languages

Comment: So, thanks for all input!

With GetTickCount and build with -0x C++: does approx 150000 ticks between the two calls
With GetTickCount in python: does approx 30000 ticks between two calls.

Not anymore a 100x fold difference, only 5x, but I still can't understand why.

Comment: you forgot getTickFrequency

Comment: Yes, probably true - because when I just run the two programs in a loop for 10 seconds, now the python program makes 170 loops, and the c++ program makes 560 loops!

Could it be that there would be a 16x tick frequency difference? What is a "tick" to opencv?